# Pass parameters to filter results through URL

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string, url-parameters

My client have a Wordpress installed an he wants, to SEO purposes, to filter results on a table passing parameters in the URL using a structure similar to this:

http://www.servihabitat.com/alquiler/local/madrid/superficie-hasta-40-obra-nueva-segunda-mano-pagina-1.htm

The filters are dash-separated: "superficie-hasta-40","obra-nueva","segunda-mano" but I am wondering how tho achieve this. How implement a code that knows what parameter on the url corresponds to each type of filter (surface,type of building,cost...)? I guess "www.servihabitat.com" is not using the position of each parameter in the url because if I add more filters the position of each parameter changes.

UPDATED:

The problem is that the filter that my client wants have 4 parameters: state,city,insurance,zip code, but not all the parameters are required so the behaviour would be something like this

```
www.domain.com/madrid/sanitas would show: www.domain.com/?city=madrid&insurance=sanitas
www.domain.com/madrid would show: www.domain.com/?city=madrid
www.domain.com/sanitas would show: www.domain.com/?insurance=sanitas
www.domain.com/spain/madrid/sanitas would show: www.domain.com/?state=spain&city=madrid&insurance=sanitas
www.domain.com/spain/madrid/sanitas/28007 would show: www.domain.com/?state=spain&city=madrid&insurance=sanitas&zip=28007
```

I don't know how to achieve this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: send the values in the following format http://www.servihabitat.com/alquiler/local/madrid?result1=superficie-hasta-40&result2=obra-nueva&result3=segunda-mano

Comment: Yes, but how can I in wordpress to rewrite that url to the "seo friendly"?